# GSP/JSP for loop - first node 'selected' class

Tags: html, jsp, grails, gsp

This is a GSP problem/niggle I've faced before in JSP and I'm looking for the cleanest possible solution.

Essentially, I'm using a for loop (`<g:each>` in GSP) to iterate through a list of items and output a HTML node for each item:

```
<g:each status="i" var="item" in="items">
    <span class="item">${item}</span>
</g:each>
```

All `<span>` nodes contain a CSS class of `item`, but I want the first node to also contain a `selected` class. Thus, I update the code to:

```
<g:each status="i" var="item" in="items">
    <g:if test="${i == 0}">
        <span class="item selected">${item}</span>
    </g:if>
    <g:else>
        <span class="item">${item}</span>
    </g:else>
</g:each>
```

This seems like a complicated approach however as I'm duplicating a lot of code. Another solution is to use a custom tag library and pass the current index into it:

```
<g:each status="i" var="item" in="items">
    <span class="item <g:getItemClass index='${i}' />">${item}</span>
</g:each>
```

The tag library will return `selected` when index is equal to 0, otherwise it won't return anything at all. Again, this adds complexity.

Other possible solutions:

- Use the index in your CSS class name (very messy)
- Set a class name var (). Not better than a custom tag imo.
- Use scriptlets (no way)

**Any other approaches to this that are clean and simple?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it's just a:

```
<g:each status="i" var="item" in="items">
    <span class="item ${i == 0 ? 'selected' : ''}">${item}</span>
</g:each>
```

Comment: Ahhh, that'd be it. Much simpler. Thanks!